# Finding cycles Depth-first-search

Tags: c#, graph, depth-first-search

I am trying to repair graphs by deleting one edges. The only problem I am running in to is, when there are multiple cycles in the graph for example: 0 3, 2 3, 0 2, 1 2, 3 1. This can be fixed by extracting 3 1, but how do I let the program no that 3 1 is the edge that has to be removed?

Any suggestions? :)

**Formatted code from comment...**

```cs
...
else if (backedges.Count > 1) 
{ 
    foreach (Side side in backedges) 
    {
        Node end = Side.node2; 
        Node begin = Side.node1; 
        List<Side> allsidesycle = new List<Side>();
        while (begin != Side.node2) 
        {
            end = begin;
            begin = begin.pi; 
            Side be = new Side(begin, end); 
            allsidescycle.Add(be); 
        }
```

Comment: You can use Dijkstra.  When you reach a node that you already visited you can remove the path to the visited node.

Comment: what have you done so far? Show us your code.

Comment: else if (backedges.Count > 1)
            {
                foreach (Side side in backedges)
                {
                    Node end = Side.node2;
                    Node begin = Side.node1;
                    List<Side> allsidesycle = new List<Side>();

                    while (begin != Side.node2)
                    {
                        end = begin;
                        begin = begin.pi;
                        Side be = new Side(begin, end);
                        allsidescycle.Add(be);
                    }

Comment: So I am looping over all the edges but I get a nullreference for begin = begin.pi.

Comment: Use the [edit] link below your question to add additional information - especially code. It doesn't display well in a comment... Also look at the information about asking thorough questions: [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

To find cycles you may want to use breadth first search (bfs). 
Using bfs on unweighted (or equally weighted) graph grantees that then the first time a node is visited is the shortest path to that node. 
If you visit it for the second time - you have a cycle. To remove it modify the graph by deleting that 2nd edge.