# how to check if a child node has multiple parents in graph? And print parents and that child

Tags: java, graph, breadth-first-search

I want to write code that traverse through the graph and check if any nodes has multiple parents. And prints the list of parents and the child node.

```
One node in the tree has multiple parents.
- Identify that node
- Identify the count of parents of that node and the return list of parents

    A
 /  |  \
B   |   C
  \ |
    D

TreeNode find_node_with_multiple_parents(TreeNode root)
List<TreeNode> find_parents_of_bad_node(TreeNode root)
```

In this graph, node D is the bad node because it has multiple parents A AND B. How can i verify if D has multiple parents?

Comment: Bfs is the right tool for the job : [When you visit a node for the second time - you have a cycle.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51121294/3992939)

Answer (score 0):

If I understood well 
A has child B,C,D
B bas child D
C has no child.
If so, if you loop over the Nodes and for every child store In a Map The number of Times you encounter that child